# PHP Web Services in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

Everybody,

Is there any tutorial or document to parse the web xml in iOS which developed in php..?
How to parse web xml and fetch data . . ? 
please help me..

Comment: Try rewording your question just a bit please. Also, do you mean XML that the phone receives from a php webserver?

Comment: i mean to, parsing (php) web xml in iOS..

Comment: XML output by PHP isn't any different than XML output by anything else.

Comment: Once again, Some one gives -ve marking to my question. Why.? I am not able  to ask the question..

Comment: xml is a possible way but I personally recommend to use JSon rather then XML. The reason is the ease of access and less memory consumption. Every PHP service is able to response in json more easily as compare to xml. You can ask me if you need help in this matter.

Comment: ya, Wasim, Thanks....    please tell me about JSON vs XML and how to parse JSON in iOS.. please let me know.. And which technologies uses in to making JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to parse data that comes back from an XML-based web service (whether SOAP, REST, or some other mechanism), the [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class gives you what you need. There are some great examples out there that show how to use this class. Just do a search for "parsing XML using NSXmlParser" and you should be able to find something.

Comment: I already know this class. But its useful for XML based web service..? If you have any doc file or blog tutorial about it than please tell me.. I am using this link for my reference http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service , Is there any more tutorial, please let me know..\

Comment: thanks, jOk. i got solution..